# Build a treeview based on common part of a set of strings

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

Let's say I have the following strings:

```
"PW_ARAY$2V_BA_A$VOT"
"PW_ARAY$2V_BA_B$VOT"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$HZ"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IB"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IN"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IR"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IW"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$MVA"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$MW"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$MX"
etc...
```

I would like to do something very generic/intelligent that can rearrange my strings in the form of a tree based on supplied separators (for instance : '_' and '$'):

```
PW
    - ARAY
        * 2V
            + BA
                - A
                    * VOT
                - B
                    * VOT
        * C0VP
            + 15
                - HZ
                - IB
                - IN
                - IR
                - IW
                - MVA
                - MW
                - MX
```

The following list should also give the same result

```
"PW_ARAY$2V_BA_A$VOT"
"PW_ARAY$2V_BA_B$VOT"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$HZ"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IB"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IN"
"PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IR"
"C0VP_15$IW"
"C0VP_15$MVA"
"C0VP_15$MW"
"C0VP_15$MX"
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks

Nic

Comment: And what if, for example, the last line was: `PW_ARAY_15$MX` instead of `C0VP_15$MX` you should have the same result again ?

Comment: No, I just want to cover the case where the first part is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (working) code sample:

```
private class Node
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    public Node Parent { get; private set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; private set; }
    public Node(string c, Node parent)
    {
        this.Value = c;
        this.Parent = parent;
        this.Children = new List<Node>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Value: " + this.Value;
    }
}

private static Node BuildTree(IEnumerable<string> tokens, char[] sep)
{
    var root = new Node(null, null);
    foreach (var token in tokens)
    {

#if OLDVERSION
        var current = root;
        var splits = token.Split(sep);
#else
        var splits = token.Split(sep);
        var current = FindFirstNodeWithValue(root, splits.First());
        if (current == null)
            current = root;
        else
            current = current.Parent;
#endif

        for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
        {
            string split = splits[i];
            var node = current.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == split);
            if (node == null)
            {
                node = new Node(split, current);
                current.Children.Add(node);
            }
            current = node;
        }
    }
    return root;
}

private static Node FindFirstNodeWithValue(Node root, string val)
{
    if (root.Value == val)
        return root;
    foreach (var child in root.Children)
    {
        var res = FindFirstNodeWithValue(child, val);
        if (res != null)
            return res;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

**Usage:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] tokens = new[]
        {
            "PW_ARAY$2V_BA_A$VOT",
            "PW_ARAY$2V_BA_B$VOT",
            "PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$HZ",
            "PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IB",
            "PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IN",
            "PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IR",
            "PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$IW",
            "PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$MVA",
            "PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$MW",
            "PW_ARAY$C0VP_15$MX",
        };

    var root = BuildTree(tokens, new[] { '_', '$' });
    // root has Value = null, but starting from the first child
    // of root you have exactly the same tree you draw in your question
}
```

Comment: EDITED: I left the original version (the one not supporting first part missing) because I think it's more reasonable (supporting missing first part could lead to misleading results IMO). Anyway, you can easily find a `#if` statement in the code splitting the two versions...

Comment: No problem, BTW the code is really really similar to this answer (mine) --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177111/how-to-make-common-prefixes-for-regex-word-stemming/4177555#4177555